# Como acerta a implementação do PageTransitions com Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Observe do site da Wix;

http://pt.wix.com/website-template/view/html/1675?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fpt.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fbusiness%2Fadvertising-marketing%2F1&bookName=create-master-new&galleryDocIndex=4&category=business&metaSiteId=

Pode ser observado que ao clicar no links como Home, Services, Work, Blog ele aplica uma implementação chamada PageTransitions com Jquery.

Eu fiz uma implementação com ajuda de alguns colaboradores do site do Stack Overflow que ficou assim;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="sistema.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>

    <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-ui.js" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.js" />
</h:head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function() {
        function transitionPage() {
            // Hide to left / show from left
            $("#home").toggle("slide", {
                direction : "left"
            }, 500);

            // Show from right / hide to right
            $("#servico").toggle("slide", {
                direction : "right"
            }, 500);
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#home').click(transitionPage);
            $('#servico').click(transitionPage);
        });
    });//]]>
</script>

<h:body>



<div id="part2">
    <div id="home">
    kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
    kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
    kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
    </div>
    <div id="servico">
    hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
    hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
    hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
    </div>
</div>




    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script
        src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</h:body>
</html>
```

sendo que mesmo assim não pegou!

O que está errado? Acredito que seja uma besteira.

Comment: encontrei modelos como esse aqui:   https://github.com/codrops/PageTransitions/tree/master/css

Comment: Tem um exemplo aqui. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/

Comment: @PauloHDSousa, exemplo que foi mostrado ainda não me faz ver aonde errei no meu projeto.